# ORACLE SQL How to use custom function iside insert cte

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-function

I am trying to use function inside insert SQL, but I am getting error   ORA-32034. Looks like that I couldn't access this function in the cte.
Maybe someone can help?

```
    insert into table1 (     

    Field1, 
    Field2, 
    Field3
 ) 

   with 


function STR_country(in_str  VARCHAR2) return char is out_str char(2);
    begin
          out_str :='';
          if    SUBSTR(in_str,1,1)= 'A'  then out_str :='AT';
          elsif SUBSTR(in_str,1,1)= 'D'  then out_str :='DE';
          elsif SUBSTR(in_str,1,2)= 'CH' then out_str :='CH';
          elsif SUBSTR(in_str,1,2)= 'CZ' then out_str :='CZ';
          elsif SUBSTR(in_str,1,1)= 'H'  then out_str :='HU';
          else  out_str := ' '; 
         end if;
          return out_str   ; 
   end;



help_select_transactions1 as
(select distinct 

    master.reference,
   f.start_date, 
   f.end_date,
   f.Branch_NO, 
   f.seq,
   master.SOURCEAPPLICATIONCODE,
   f.PAYRECIND,
   f.NOSTRODDAINDICATOR,
   f.PAYMENTVALUEDATE,
   f.PAYMENTCURRENCY,
   f.PAYMENTAMOUNT,
  STR_country(customer1.address3)   as customer_country,
   STR_country(customer2.address3)   as customer_country2)
```

Comment: What version of Oracle is your database?

Comment: You need `/*+ WITH_PLSQL */` hint. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=302dff23e57b85bbf9f16232e73ad44a).

Comment: Just FYI, https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#with-plsql-hint

Comment: @PonderStibbons, Please post your comment as answer as this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the query containing the PL/SQL declaration section is not the top
>   level query, the top-level query must include the WITH_PLSQL hint.
>   Without this hint, the statement will fail to compile

This says [documentation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#with-plsql-hint). So in this case you will probably need:

```
insert /*+ WITH_PLSQL*/ into table1 (Field1, Field2, ...
```

<sup>**[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=302dff23e57b85bbf9f16232e73ad44a)** with similiar table</sup>